# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

Why does this procedure not work?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_top5_v2_type_1km]
    @IdCustomer int,
    @idGroupVehicle int  
AS
    DECLARE @start geography
    SET @start = (SELECT location FROM Customer 
                  WHERE idCustomer = @idCustomer )

    SELECT TOP 5 
        idVehicle, idGroupVehicle, brand, model, maxRange, weight, maxSpeed, nameLocation 
    FROM 
        Vehicle 
    WHERE 
        idGroupVehicle = @idGroupVehicle 
        AND @start.STDistance(locationVehicle) / 1000 <= 1
    ORDER BY 
        @start.STDistance(locationVehicle) / 1000 ASC
GO
```

This procedure should list top 5 vehicles which is the nearest and type vehicle is by `idGroupVehicle` but I get this error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure p_top5_type, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 18]
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Can someone explain why this does not work?

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear.

Comment: what i must to change in this query ?

Comment: i dont understand why i dont see my top 5 vehicle by idCustomer and by idGroupVehicle

Comment: The problem is your **subquery** as the error tells you. Clearly the column `idCustomer` is not a unique value in your table `Customet`.

Comment: Also, I really suggest better use of white space and line breaks. Don't put queries on a single line; it makes longer ones very difficult to read.

Comment: i solve this when i use ```(and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 <=1)```

Comment: yes is better when is more lines query than in one i know xd

Comment: `SELECT TOP(1) location` perhaps just as the error states when it attempts to assign multiple values.

Comment: The OP will need to add an `ORDER BY` too @MarkSchultheiss , other wise `TOP 1` might as well say "any arbitrary row".

Comment: yea, but that is outside the scope of the error although still important - probably need to have a better scope on the `WHERE` clause for the correct value on that spatial type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It's certainly in scope to have the `ORDER BY` with a `TOP`, @MarkSchultheiss . There's no point fixing one flaw if you're going to introduce another.

Comment: Yes, a `TOP` should always have an `ORDER BY` as best practice so I will include a reference to my comment (vs posting an answer) ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

> Subuery => (SELECT location FROM Customer
> WHERE idCustomer = @idCustomer )
> return more then one value
> it occur when you use SET syntax

I think you have double idCustomer in table Customer

if you can use double idCustomer in table Customer

```sql
 SET @start = (SELECT TOP 1 location FROM Customer 
                  WHERE idCustomer = @idCustomer )
```

Or

```sql
SELECT @start = location FROM Customer 
WHERE idCustomer = @idCustomer
```